# Nokia Lumia 530 ear phones not working

Tags: music

My Lumia 530 played my music files for years via my earphones
Last week it suddenly after charging overnight did not play my music via the ear phones.
I tried and was able to play music over the speaker, but not via ear phones.
I can hear ring tones, and can have phone conversations with my ear phones plugged in.
Is there a setting where I can mute un-mute the earbuds in music mode?
I have looked for but was unable to find it.
I have switched off the phone removed the battery and re-started but that did not help.
I also backed up and reset the phone to no avail.
Please any pointers to solve this problem.